# How can I get all components of a type from a List with mixed components?

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I have a list of `GameObjects`.  Half of these `GameObjects` have `Component1`, and the other half have `Component2`.  I want to get all of `Component1` from the list.

So an example of my list:

```
var list = new List<GameObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new GameObject());
}
foreach(var go in list)
{
    if(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) < 0.5f)
    {
        go.AddComponent<Component1>();
    }
    else
    {
        go.AddComponent<Component2>();
    }
}
```

I can get all of `Component2` by using LINQ as such:

```
var components1 = list.Where(g => g.GetComponent<Component1>()).Select(r => r.GetComponent<Component1>()).ToList();
```

But that is very dirty and seems repetitive.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using LINQ is probably the easiest / cleanest / shortest way to do it afaik.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is probably the best way to go, but switch your Select and Where so you don't have to call `GetComponent` twice

```
var components1 = list.Select(r => r.GetComponent<Component1>()).Where(g => g!= null).ToList();
```